# How to download from a server asynchronously in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to download data from a server line by line **asynchronously**. Actually, I used Kotlin Coroutines, but when I connected the httpurlconnection in the async lambda block, it showed a warning that the method will be blocked there, so I was unable to perform the request asynchronously.

This is the code :

```kotlin
fun download(urlString : String) = runBlocking{
    val url = URL(urlString)
    val httpurlconnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    httpurlconnection.setRequestMethod("GET")
    val response = async {
        httpurlconnection.connect()
        val scanner = java.util.Scanner(httpurlconnection.inputstream)
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            val string = scanner.nextLine()
            println(string)
            sb.append(string)
        }
        sb.toString()
    }
    println("length of response = ${response.length}")
}
```

Comment: What's the point in reading the body line by line if you're building a full string out of it anyway? Why read the whole stream into a string right away?

Comment: Also what exactly are you trying to make asynchronous here? In your current code, `download()` is blocking: it will not return until the body is fully downloaded. You should probably explain a bit more what you're trying to achieve here. Do you want `download()` to be completely async in the sense that the caller can move on while the download happens?

Comment: I have edited the question to remove the request for finding a library, as I think that was the result of an XY problem, and the core issue is one others might have in the future and there's a good answer that solves it. In the revised state, I believe the question should be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. your whole current `download()` function is blocking the current thread anyway because of `runBlocking`. The method will not be asynchronous if you block the current thread during the whole time of the request. There is no point is starting a single `async` coroutine inside it if you're blocking the current thread to wait for it.
2. the warning you are getting is because you're using a blocking API from within a coroutine, which is usually discouraged because it blocks the thread that the coroutine is running on, and is not how coroutines were designed to be used.
3. the current code is reading all lines from the body to build a single `String` out of it, which makes reading line-by line a bit pointless.

For issue #1, you can make your function asynchronous by declaring it as a `suspend` function instead of using `runBlocking`, and you can get rid of `async`. This does shift the burden of handling the asynchrony at the call site of `download()`, though. You'll need to call it within a coroutine (using a coroutine builder like `async`), and you'll need a coroutine scope for that.

For issue #2, the usual workaround is to just execute the blocking calls in a `withContext(Disptachers.IO) { ... }` block, so they are done in a thread pool that will create new threads as needed for the IO operations. If you can use an async API instead, you don't have to resort to that, as you can just map these APIs to the coroutines model.

In this case, `HttpUrlConnection` is an inconvenient low-level API, in addition to being blocking. If you're running on JRE 11+, you can use the asynchronous API of the built-in JDK11 `HttpClient` instead, and adapt it to coroutines.

Ignoring issue #3 for the moment, since your current code is reading the full body anyway, a simple equivalent would be the following:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.future.await
import java.net.URI
import java.net.http.*

suspend fun download(urlString : String): String {
    val client = HttpClient.newHttpClient()
    val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(urlString)).build()
    val futureResponse = client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
    // await() adapts the async Java future API to the coroutine world.
    // It suspends until the response is received (in a non-blocking way)
    // and until the full body is read and converted to a String
    return futureResponse.await().body()
}
```

This method suspends until the response is received. You can use coroutines to manage the way you call this function.

Back to issue #3, if you really want to process lines as they come, you can use one of the [BodyHandlers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.html) that stream the response line by line instead, such as [BodyHandlers.ofLines()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.html#ofLines()):

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.future.await
import kotlinx.coroutines.stream.consumeAsFlow
import java.net.URI
import java.net.http.*

suspend fun downloadLines(urlString : String): Flow<String> {
    val client = HttpClient.newHttpClient()
    val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(urlString)).build()
    val futureResponse = client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofLines())
    // await() here only waits for the reponse to arrive,
    // it doesn't wait until the full response body is read.
    // Instead, the Stream<String> returned by body() provides
    // the body lines as they come
    return futureResponse.await().body().consumeAsFlow()
}
```

This method suspends until the call is made, but may return before the response is read. Collecting the returned flow is the way to read the body lines of the response as they are streamed from the server.

Another option is to use [Ktor HTTP client](https://ktor.io/docs/getting-started-ktor-client.html), and [read from the response](https://ktor.io/docs/response.html) body little by little. See how to read the response, or more specifically the [response streaming documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/streaming.html).
I have to admit the documentation is quite succinct, though. So you usually have to figure out the details yourself.

Comment: You mention that it’s preferable to use APIs that already asynchronous and map that to coroutines and the reasoning sounds like your are implying that APIs like that are not blocking threads, which cannot be true. They would be using their own thread pool instead of Dispatchers.IO. Is there some other reason to avoid Dispatchers.IO?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Some async libraries can make use of natively non-blocking mechanisms (e.g. NuProcess), or use non-blocking polling, they don't have to block threads. That being said, I believe most of them do use their own threads under the hood (and actually it's the case of JDK11's HttpClient), so my implication is bad in this answer, thanks for pointing this out. I will change this part of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I didn't know about NuProcess.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're currently using `runBlocking`.

You need to launch it in a coroutine scope to make it asynchronous, additionally you can switch the operation to `IO`.

```
suspend fun download(urlString : String): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
    ...
}
```

And call it from your specific coroutine scope, for ex:

```
MainScope().launch {
    val result = download(baseUrl)
}
```